# How to make Integration Tests coverage measurable?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

Our project is done using Spring Boot and we split our unit tests and integration tests approaches in the following manner:

1. Unit tests are run as JUnit test cases.
2. Integration tests are run as Cucumber scenarios but the implementation of the tests are done by triggering `RestTemplate` / `HttpClient` calls to a running instance of the Spring Boot service that is deployed after unit tests have passed.

We did the Integration tests the way I described it above as there was an expectation that the tests must also verify that the app is able to perform as designed in an actual deployed environment.

But my problem is that when I do externalized testing in this manner, I can't find a way to objectively measure my coverage the way I can do using Jacoco during unit tests.

Is there some tool that can be instrumented into a Spring Boot app's runtime to measure coverage of code branches while it is run in a deployed environment? Or do I need to run integration tests as described in the Spring Boot documentation where we simulate the environment using annotations while still in our Jenkins workflow (i.e. not deployed yet).